# create dataframe in scala with List of strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have data coming as List[String], where as each string is a row and columns are seperated by comma. I have to create a data frame so that i can query data by creating a view on top that. 
Can some one please guide me how we can convert this to Dataframe.

`List[String] = List([Table,EXTERNAL,hive,name1],[Table,EXTERNAL,hive,name2],[Table,EXTERNAL,hive,name3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = List("Table,EXTERNAL,hive,name1","Table,EXTERNAL,hive,name2","Table,EXTERNAL,hive,name3")
  .map(_.split(",") match {
    case Array(table, tableType, db, name) => (table, tableType, db, name)
  })
  .toDF("table", "type", "db", "name")
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

which prints:

```
+-----+--------+----+-----+
|table|    type|  db| name|
+-----+--------+----+-----+
|Table|EXTERNAL|hive|name1|
|Table|EXTERNAL|hive|name2|
|Table|EXTERNAL|hive|name3|
+-----+--------+----+-----+

root
 |-- table: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- db: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```